# what is the scheduling algorithm followed in mac os?

Tags: macos, scheduling

what is the scheduling algorithm followed in mac os ?

where can i find the relevant document. did a google search but didnt get any useful resource ..

Thanks

Comment: http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/ancient/whatismacosx/arch_xnu.html, http://neosmart.net/blog/2008/os-x-snow-leopard-to-use-ule-scheduler/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Kernel Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/), chapter [Mach Scheduling and Thread Interfaces](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/scheduler/scheduler.html).

Answer (score -3):

You can read the source for OS X's kernel at [Apple's open source site](http://www.opensource.apple.com/).